Correct test for regression with more than two factor levels?
Is it correct to use a "post hoc test" (e.g. a Tukey test) to analyse differences among factor levels in a linear regression or is there another method that is preferred?
In my case, I have a mixed-effects logistic regression with two factors and their interaction. One factor has two levels (so no problem) and the other has three levels. I need to test the differences between the two levels of this second factor that are not tested in the regression.
I've used the ghlt function in the multcomp package (after making a new variable for the interaction term) which gives me all 15 pairwise comparisons with adjusted p-values. Is this the best way? Or should I have perhaps run a likelihood ratio test, which shows adding the two predictor variables does not significantly add to the null model, or a different method altogether?

"I need to test the differences between the two levels of this second factor that are not tested in the regression." If this is all you need, you may code the factor in such a way that the relevant difference is actually tested in the regression.

@mkt Maybe it was the wrong term to use. I meant planned before starting data analysis

@ChristianHennig How do I do this? Is this the norm?

There's quite a bit on this on the web, e.g.,  https://bookdown.org/pingapang9/linear_models_bookdown/chap-contrasts.html or https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-test-contrasts-in-r/ Not sure what "the norm" is, but as I said before, if what I cited there is all you want to do, that's how to do it.
